# How to loop though an array and create an array, in the loop, containing values from the original array?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Hey everyone I have a question about arrays and loops in PHP.

For a game I'm making, I need to write a function that generates a stack of crystal_id's based on a given size and ratio.
The ratio is the ratio between black crystals and different colored crystal (so a ratio of 0,25 (1:4) and a stack of 50 would yield a stack with 40 black crystals and 10 colored crystals).
I have all the math to calculate the amount of crystals per color and stuff figured out, but I can't figure out how to create an array with the right amount of colored crystals where each color is represented equally.

For reference, the array the code gets to choose from is a variable called `$crystals_array`, which is an array filled with integers where each integer represents a different colored crystal (e.g. [2,3,4,5,6]).

In the above case we have 5 different colored crystals and we needed a total of 10 colored crystals where each crystal is represented equally. So I need to create an array that looks a little something like this:
[2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6].

The code I have so far is this:

```
    for($i = 0; $i <= count($amount_crystals_color) - 1; $i++)
    {
        $array = array_fill(0, $amount_crystals_per_color_stack, $crystals_array[$i]);
        $i++;
    }
```

Using the above example `$amount_crystals_per_color_stack` is equal to 2 and `amount_crystals_color` is equal to 5.
When executing this code it outputs an array: [2,2] which is how many 2's we need, but I can't figure out how to add the remaining crystals to this array.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: you want to duplicate your array element, right??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several problems and i will address each of them individually.

**Using the `for` loop to iterate over an array**

You are using a for loop in your code, that has the following loop head:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($crystals_array) - 1; $i++)
```

The loop had consists of three parts, each separated by a semicolon (`;`).

1. The first part `$i = 0` is the initialization part. Here you initialize a variable, that is later used as an iterator, which shall change in each loop iteration. You could name this the start point as well.
2. The second part `$i <= count($crystals_array) - 1` is the condition part. A condition is formed, that shall express for how long the loop shall iterate. As long as the expression evaluates as true, the loop will run again. Therefore this condition is evaluated at the start of each iteration. As soon as the condition evaluates as false the loop will end. Therefore this part can be named endpoint as well.
3. The third part `$i++` is the step size. This is executed at the end of each iteration and determines how the iterator (the variable you defined in the first part) shall change. `$i++` is *in this context* equal to `$i = $i + 1` and represents a step size of 1. Therefore the variable `$i` gets increased by 1 for each run of the loop.

This said, you can improve and fix your code regarding the `for` loop with two changes:

1. Save functions, that are executed in your condition part into an variable, if they return a constant result for each iteration. You use the `count()` function, which will then count your array again for each iteration of the `for` loop. By saving it in a variable `$count = count($crystals_array);` before the `for` loop and changing the condition to `$i < $count`, the function is only called once and your code gets faster.
2. Do not change the iterator variable `$i` outside of your loop header. This is really bad code style. You added the line `$i++;` to the end of your loop, but that is already done in the step size part of the `for` header. Because that is executed at the and of each iteration as well you increased the step size to two, meaning that you only run the for loop with `$i = 0`, `$i = 2` and `$i = 4` instead of for each element.

For your code the usage of the `$i` iterator is only to address the elements of the initial array. Even though you should understand the `for` loop for the future, you should use a `foreach` loop for this case instead. The following code would be equivalent to your `for` loop.

```
//This code still contains another major bug and is jsut a partial improvvement
foreach($crystals_array as $crystal) {
    $array = array_fill(0, $amount_crystals_per_color_stack, $crystal);
}
```

As you can see, you neither need to worry about counting the initial array, nor in which index the current value is. Instead the variable `$crystal` will automatically contain the next element for each iteration.

**Appending elements to an array**

You used the following line to save the newly generated elements in your array:

```
$array = array_fill(0, $amount_crystals_per_color_stack, $crystal);
```

If you look closely, you use a standard assignment with `$array =` at the beginning of your line. This means, that (like with each variable assignment) the previous value of the variable gets overwritten by the new value provided from the right side of the assignment. What you do not want yet is to overwrite the array, but to append something to it.

This can be done by adding two squared brackets to the end of the variable name: `$array[] = ...`. Now, if the variable `$array` is really an array, what ever value is on the right side of the assignment will be appended to the array, instead of overwriting it.

**Managing result types the right way**

The following line still contains a major problem:

```
$array[] = array_fill(0, $amount_crystals_per_color_stack, $crystal);
```

The result type of `array_fill()` is an array itself. By appending it  to the previous array, you would get the following structure:

```
$array = [
    [2, 2],
    [3, 3],
    [4, 4],
    [5, 5],
    [6, 6],
];
```

As you can see, the code did exactly what it should but not what you wanted. Each result (array) was appended to the array. The result is therefore an array or arrays (or a multidimensional array). What you want instead, is that the values of the result are appended to the existing array.

PHP offers a function for that, named [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). This function takes all elements for one (or more) array(s) and appends them to the end of the first array, that was given to the function. You can use it as followed:

```
$newCrystals = array_fill(0, $amount_crystals_per_color_stack, $crystal);
$array = array_merge($array, $newCrystals);
```

As you can see the latter line contains a normal assignment again. (`$array =`) This is because `array_merge()` does not modify the first array given to it, but creates a new array with the merged fields. Therefore the new array contains all values from the old one and it is safe to overwrite the old one with it.

The complete code would therefore be:

```
$array = [];
foreach($crystals_array as $crystal) {
    $newCrystals = array_fill(0, $amount_crystals_per_color_stack, $crystal);
    $array = array_merge($array, $newCrystals);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the incredibly detailed explanation. As a novice programmer currently studying CS stuff like this really helps. I ended up using code another commenter provided, but I wanted to thank you for the time it must have taken to write this.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the problem

```
$crystals_array = [2,3,4,5,6];
$amount_crystals_per_color_stack = 2;

$res = [];

foreach($crystals_array as $v) {
  // repeat each item from array $amount_crystals_per_color_stack times
  $res = array_merge($res, array_fill(0, $amount_crystals_per_color_stack, $v));
}

print_r($res); // [2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge your array at each iteration of the loop ([repl online](https://repl.it/repls/KaleidoscopicAnguishedZenaida)) or you lose the result each time.

Like:

```
$array = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($amount_crystals_color); $i++)
    {
        $array = array_merge($array, array_fill(0, $amount_crystals_per_color_stack, $crystals_array[$i]);
    }
```

Also you don't need the `$i++` in the loop, because it iterate twice otherwise, and you don't need `count(..)-1` if the condition is `<` instead of `<=`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple `foreach()` to achieve this-

```
$amount_crystals_per_color_stack = 2;
$array = [2,3,4,5,6];
$result = array();
foreach($array as $a){
    for($i=1;$i<=$amount_crystals_per_color_stack;$i++){
        array_push($result, $a);
    }
}
print_r($result);
```